# Adding Days to defined date on XSLT

Tags: xslt

im trying to add seven days from my defined day, 
i've a defined date like this

```
//n1:Invoice/cbc:IssueDate
```

i m using date like this and it works

```
<xsl:value-of select="//n1:Invoice/cbc:IssueDate" />
```

that turns me `20-01-2016`
and i want to print seven days after this date like:

```
27-01-2016
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 5 business days to an existing value xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306380/how-to-add-5-business-days-to-an-existing-value-xslt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I use `xs:date()` and `xs:dayTimeDuration()` to get it done.

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="xs:date(
                  string-join(reverse(tokenize(//n1:Invoice/cbc:IssueDate, '-')), '-')) + 
                  xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D')"/>
```

would add 7 days to your value.

> Note: you will need xs namespace for that (`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`)

Comment: This (1) requires XSLT 2.0 and (2) will not work with OP's date format.

Comment: hi, i try it and i get an error like this: The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'string-join' is not a valid XSLT or XPath function. xs:date( -->string-join(reverse(tokenize(//n1:Invoi...